# Modified getLoadedProductCollection on product listing page shows wrong product count

Tags: magento-2.1, product-collection

I want to **filter product collection based on custom attribute** on product listing page.

So I have to override `_getProductCollection` function from `\vendor\magento\module-catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct.php` in my customm module.

Below is my code:

```
 protected function _getProductCollection()
 {
    if ($this->_productCollection === null) {
        $layer = $this->getLayer();

        /* @var $layer \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer */
        if ($this->getShowRootCategory()) {
            $this->setCategoryId($this->_storeManager->getStore()->getRootCategoryId());
        }

        // if this is a product view page
        if ($this->_coreRegistry->registry('product')) {
            // get collection of categories this product is associated with
            $categories = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('product')
                ->getCategoryCollection()->setPage(1, 1)
                ->load();
            // if the product is associated with any category
            if ($categories->count()) {
                // show products from this category
                $this->setCategoryId(current($categories->getIterator()));
            }
        }

        $origCategory = null;
        if ($this->getCategoryId()) {
            try {
                $category = $this->categoryRepository->get($this->getCategoryId());
            } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
                $category = null;
            }

            if ($category) {
                $origCategory = $layer->getCurrentCategory();
                $layer->setCurrentCategory($category);
            }
        }
        $this->_productCollection = $layer->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('my_attribute_name', array('neq' => NULL));



        $this->prepareSortableFieldsByCategory($layer->getCurrentCategory());

        if ($origCategory) {
            $layer->setCurrentCategory($origCategory);
        }
    }

    return $this->_productCollection;
}
```

using this my filtered product shown in front side but it give wrong product count.

can any one help me?

Answer (score 1):

It's a Magento default bug, Issue is solved here.

[Fixing issue with getSize function not recalculating after adding filters.](https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/10246/commits/676930547154a428fc2b5ce2565b1d6e8edb524f)

Replace getSize() function code by below code

```
public function getSize()
    {
        $itemCount = count($this->_items);
        if ($this->_totalRecords === null || ($itemCount > 0 && $itemCount !== $this->_totalRecords)) {
            $sql = $this->getSelectCountSql();
            $this->_totalRecords = (int) $this->getConnection()->fetchOne($sql, $this->_bindParams);
        }
        return (int) $this->_totalRecords;
    }
```

You can fix it by apply given changes to your core file.

Core file Path : `vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection/AbstractDb.php`

**Note:** This is a temporary solution.

Comment: @ suresh Chikani: can you please provide me core full path in magento 2?

Comment: check my updated answer.

Comment: can any one give me permanent solution, without changing in core file?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is right solution but this can solve problem without changing in core file.

I used plugin to override method.

Declare plugin di.xml file.

**app/code/Package/Module/etc/di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb">
    <plugin name="Package_Module_Framework_Data_Collection_AbstractDb" type="Package\Module\Plugin\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb" sortOrder="10" disabled="false"  />
</type>
```

Then create plugin file in

**app/code/Package/Module/Plugin/Framework/Data/Collection/AbstractDb.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

namespace Package\Module\Plugin\Framework\Data\Collection;

class AbstractDb
{
    public function afterGetSize(
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $AbstractDb,
        $totalRecords) {

        $this->_totalRecords = $totalRecords;
        if($this->_totalRecords == 1)
        {
            $sql = $AbstractDb->getSelectCountSql();
            $this->_totalRecords = $AbstractDb->getConnection()->fetchAll($sql);
            //$this->_totalRecords = $AbstractDb->getConnection()->fetchAll($sql,$AbstractDb->_bindParams);
            $this->_totalRecords = count($this->_totalRecords);
        }
        return (int) $this->_totalRecords;

    }
}
```